# geom_area stacks areas by default

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `geom_area` to plot a very simple dataset. When plotting using `geom_line` everything is normal but when I switch to `geom_area` higher values getting plotted. I think looking at the graphs would be the best way of representing my problem:

```
require(tidyverse)

x <- structure(list(Time = 0:40, X15.DCIA = c(0, 1, 0.5, 0, 2, 2.5, 
      1, 0.5, 0, 1, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 3, 
      5, 7, 6.5, 5.5, 4, 3, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
      X100.DCIA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5, 7, 8, 7.5, 6.5, 5, 3.5, 2.25, 
      1.75, 1.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-41L))

 x %>% gather(prct.DCIA, Vol, -Time) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Vol)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=prct.DCIA))


 x %>% gather(prct.DCIA, Vol, -Time) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Vol)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill=prct.DCIA))
```

[image: plotst]

The `geom_line` is what I expected (a line plot of my data).

But then looking at the `geom_area` you see that `100DCIA` has jumped up-to 15.

I am more interested in an **explanation** rather than a fix or workaround.

***Note:***

This can be a workaround:

```
x %>% gather(prct.DCIA, Vol, -Time) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Vol)) + 
      geom_polygon(aes(fill=prct.DCIA, alpha=0.5)) + guides(alpha=FALSE)
```

Comment: If you put the `aplha = 0.5` outside the `aes` bracket, per below, you won't need the `guides(alpha = FALSE)` call on the 'workaround'

Comment: @Umaomamaomao That's not my personal preference, thx tho

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Explanation:**
Your plots are stacking on top of one another.

The values you see following the red line in the `geom_area` graph are the sum of the values for the red and blue lines in your `geom_line` graph.

You can see this clearly if you separate out `prct.DCIA` with `facet_grid()`:

```
x %>% gather(prct.DCIA, Vol, -Time) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Vol)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill=prct.DCIA)) + facet_grid(.~prct.DCIA)
```

[image]

This is simply because `position = "stack"` [is the default argument in](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_ribbon.html) `geom_area`:

> ```
> geom_area(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
>   position = "stack", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
>   inherit.aes = TRUE, ...)
> ```

One might presume this is because people use `geom_area` because they want to show the whole area on a diagram, rather than fill under some lines. Generally bars or area might represent a count of something, or the area filled in represents something, while points or lines may represent a point estimate and the area above or below the line or point isn't meaningful.

Cf. [the default argument for](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html) `geom_line` is `position = "identity"`.

> ```
> geom_line(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity",
>   position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
>   inherit.aes = TRUE, ...)
> ```

**Fix:**
If you use `position = position_dodge()` you can see they return to looking like the line graph, with the red area is plotted behind the blue area:

```
  x %>% gather(prct.DCIA, Vol, -Time) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Vol)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill=prct.DCIA), position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

You can even set `alpha` < 1 and see this clearly:

```
x %>% gather(prct.DCIA, Vol, -Time) %>% ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Vol)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill=prct.DCIA), position = position_dodge(), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still need to know why the default behaviour of `gem_area` is stacked. Moreover, I looked at the first version of your answer and think that the `facet` you provided is a good point. So, I'd include/add it in the answer; but at the end, it's your call. Cheers.

Comment: OK I've added that back. I'm not sure what more explanation there can be for the default behaviour of something other than that it is specified as the default behaviour but I've expanded on this above. More than that and you might have to ask Hadley Wickham why this takes his fancy...

Comment: Maybe the thinking goes geom area for stacked and geom poly for dodge.