# Why geom_area creates this extra filling on top?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following use-case for plotting the line but also the areas under the line and preferably that don't overlap so I can see both colors e.g.

```
library(ggplo2)

dfc <- data.frame(n=c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30), Type=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), val=c(10, 20, 30, 10, 14, 11))
ggplot(dfc, aes(n, val, color=Type, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) + geom_line(size=1) + geom_area(alpha=0.2, position=position_stack()) + 
  geom_line(aes()) + 
  expand_limits(x=10, y=0)
```

However, it creates a weird red area above the near linear line which I don't understand and can't get rid of.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `position` is set to `stack`, which in this case means the upper area will sit on top of the lower area. Perhaps you are looking for `position = identity`.

Here is a similar post with some hints: [geom_area plots stacked areas by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53549657/12400385)

```
ggplot(dfc, aes(n, val, color=Type, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) + 
  geom_line(size=1) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.2, position = 'identity')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @nniloc but it doesnt work for me. I see all the area red, like if red is filled on top of the greenish blue. How can you use identity reverse=TRUE?

Comment: Never mind, using `forcats::fct_rev()` on the aes bit for color and fill fixes the issue.